# История посещёний сайтов firefox с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, firefox

Подскажите библиотеку с помощью которой можно следить за посещением страниц , чтобы когда я переходила с одного сайта на другой - адрес сайта записывался в файл.

Нужно доставать URL с посещённого сайта из браузера Firefox. ОС - Debian based linux.

Comment: Как минимум PyCap

Comment: C https будут проблемы у Вас.

Comment: Но если сделать свой socks сервер / vpn / proxy с подменой сертификатов - ничего невозможного нет. Самовыпущенный сертификат должен быть добавлен в доверенные на целевой машине.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, а как scapy?

Comment: вы только имена сайтов хотите или вместе с адресами страниц? Вам только из браузера нужно или запоминать http(s)-запросы любым способом созданные?

Comment: @jfs, только из браузера адреса страниц.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы напечатать ссылки, известные firefox, достаточно прочитать [`places.sqlite` базу данных](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Database) из соответствующего [firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Print urls from given firefox profile.

Usage: firefox-urls <profile-dir>

Example: firefox-urls ~/.mozilla/firefox/4dfb4drtz.default

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Database
"""
import os
import sqlite3
import sys

try:
    db = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(sys.argv[1], 'places.sqlite'))
    urls = db.execute('select url from moz_places')
except (IndexError, sqlite3.OperationalError):
    sys.exit(__doc__)  # print usage and exit


for [url] in urls: 
    print(url)
```

`moz_historyvisits` таблица содержит каждое посещение страницы (дата, referrer и ссылка на `moz_places` таблицу с соответствующим URL). К примеру, чтобы вывести адреса страниц и местное время когда они были посещены за сегодня (с начала UTC дня):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Print urls of visited pages [UTC] today from the default firefox profile.

Usage: firefox-day-history
"""
import datetime as DT
import os
import sqlite3
from pathlib import Path

firefox_dir = Path('~/.mozilla/firefox/').expanduser()
db_path = next(firefox_dir.glob('*.default/places.sqlite'))
db = sqlite3.connect(os.fspath(db_path))

for visit_date, url in db.execute(
        "select h.visit_date, p.url"
        " from moz_historyvisits as h, moz_places as p"
        " where date(h.visit_date/1000000, 'unixepoch') == date('now')"
        " and p.id == h.place_id order by h.visit_date"):
    print(DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(visit_date//1000000).time(), url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать [scapy](https://github.com/secdev/scapy).

Вот небольшой пример снифа в консоль:

```
# pip install scapy
from scapy.all import sniff


def _packethandler(pkt):
    data = pkt.summary()
    print(data)


sniff(filter="tcp", prn=_packethandler)
```

---

Возможно, с HTTPS сайтами этот пример не заработает